# Add an array of custom objects to Core Data

Tags: swift, class, core-data

I've searched all over StackOverflow already and it seems there are a few posts on this topic but either they are outdated or the solutions don't actually address the problem specifically.

I have a custom class called ProductDataModel. Then I have an array of these custom class objects of ProductDataModel. I want to save this array to coreData as an attribute. I have it set to the type of Transformable, but when I try to save it, the program crashes.

How do I save an array of custom objects to a core data property?

I have already made the class model inherit from NSObject.

Comment: Tried Code ? and your core Data Screenshot where you declared this transformable Property

Comment: please show your code ([mcve])

Comment: It's highly recommended to create an entity from the custom class and use a Core Data relationship. A transformable is inappropriate in this case especially for performance reasons

Comment: How are these other answers outdated? Other people have needed to do this, asked, and received answers.